# How to Generate Thumbnail for File Stored on Rackspace CloudFiles

Tags: image-processing, thumbnails, rackspace, cloudfiles

I stored images using [Rackspace CloudFiles](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/files/). Now I want to display it as a gallery in the browser. Is there any way to generate thumbnails from my files from the Rackspace side?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: The answer is no. The Cloud Files API [bit.ly/1iCZi7e] offers no such options. It would be really handy as there can sometimes be considerable lag when a script has to download a full size image to generate a thumbnail on the fly. If you do need to generate thumbnails on the fly then I'd recommend the approach of setting the thumbnail's src with the URL of a server side script, that outputs the thumbnail. Make sure the script is also running under a different domain to that of the webpage, to avoid the process from seizing up the current user's session.

Answer (score 2):

While there's not a way to do this with the Rackspace or OpenStack Swift libraries, you can create thumbnails for the images programmatically and upload those.

## Python - pyrax + PIL (pillow)

For instance, if you're using Python you can use [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (PIL) to create thumbnails and [pyrax to upload](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax/blob/master/docs/cloud_files.md). You'll need to `pip install` both of these. Prior to installing Pillow, make sure to install system packages for libjpeg and libpng (or follow the instructions in Pillow's [installation documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#simple-installation)).

```python
import os
from StringIO import StringIO

import pyrax
from PIL import Image

# Authenticate with Rackspace
pyrax.set_setting("identity_type", "rackspace")
pyrax.set_credential_file(os.path.expanduser("~/.rax_creds"))
cs = pyrax.cloudservers
cf = pyrax.cloudfiles

# Get the container we'll be uploading to
gallery = cf.get_container("gallery")

# Arbitrarily setting a thumbnail size
maxwidth=64
maxheight=64

infile = os.path.expanduser("~/mommapanda.jpg")
# We'll use StringIO to simulate a file
out = StringIO()

im = Image.open(infile)

im.thumbnail((maxwidth,maxheight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save(out, "PNG")

# Back to the start of our "file"
out.seek(0)

gallery.store_object("mommapanda.thumb.png", out.read(),
                     content_type="image/png")
```

The above code turns this big image

[image: momma panda]

into this thumbnail

[image: momma panda thumbnail]

and uploads it to a container called gallery on CloudFiles.